# Removing Trend Micro resulted in not being able to access the Internet

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

We've currently got Trend Micro as our anti-virus, but will be switching to Symantec Endpoint Protection (SEP).  (This is for Windows XP and Windows 7 machines.)  My co-worker removed Trend Micro, but couldn't install SEP, because it wasn't able to access the Internet.  She suspects that removing Trend Micro resulted in her not being able to access the Internet.  If that is the case, then what do we do about it?

Comment: Our connection to the Internet is poor, so we had to get SEP on a USB drive to install it from there.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your co-worker didn't follow [the proper instructions for removing TM](http://esupport.trendmicro.com/Pages/How-do-I-remove-Trend-Micro-Internet-Security-Pro-and-Trend-Micro-Inte.aspx). The first step would be to use a system restore point to put TM back. Next she will need to use the Trend Micro Diagnostic Toolkit to uninstall TM(the 32 bit version is [here](http://solutionfile.trendmicro.com/solutionfile/EN-1037161/32bit.exe)).

After that, do the following:

Part I

1. Go To Control Panel
2. Click Network And Internet
3. Click Network And Sharing Center
4. Click Manage Network Connections
5. Click Local Area Connection
6. Under the General tab, click on Properties
7. On the list, click on the Trend Micro Common Firewall Driver
8. Click on the Uninstall button
9. Click on Yes for confirmation

Part II

1. Click on the Start Menu.
2. Click on All Programs.
3. Click on the Accessories folder.
4. Right-click on Command Prompt and options will appear.
5. Click on the Run As Administrator option and a new window will appear.
     Note: If a pop-up message appears, click on the Continue button.
6. Type the following:
     **netsh winsock reset**
7. Click on the Enter key of your keyboard and a message will appear.
8. Restart your computer for the changes to take effect.

I hope this helps